# Cannot Parse Json sub object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I am using `JObject` to parse `Json` object below

```
string Jstring = @"{
  "PolicyId" :"xxxxxx",
  "PolicyHolder" :{"title":"Mr", "FirstName":"test", "LastName":"testLast"}
}";
```

I can get the `PolicyId` value through below code

```
Jobject jobj = Jobject.parse(Jstring);
string PolicyId = jobj.value<string>("PolicyId");
```

But, I always get `null` using below code:

```
string Holder = jobj.value<string>("PolicyHolder");
```

I have debugged the code below:

```
jobj.Properties()
```

I can find `PolicyHolder` in the List. I have tried code below also, the value is always `null`

```
JProperty jproperty = jobj.Properties().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PolicyHolder");
```

Can anyone know what happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string Holder = jobj.value<string>("PolicyHolder");
```

Above line fails because `PolicyHolder` is not `string`. You are trying to cast it to `string`. It's an `object`. You must create a class with the properties of the `PolicyHolder` and use that as a type instead of `string`.

Comment: Thanks！ I found that I have to assign it to the JToken  object

Comment: No worries. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's the working dotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xOOl5m

Console Output:

[image: parse json sub object]

Here are the classes I ended up declaring and using.

```
public class PolicyHolder
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Policy
{
    public string PolicyId { get; set; }
    public PolicyHolder PolicyHolder { get; set; }
}
```

Like [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2545042/sam) has mentioned, `PolicyHolder` is an `Object` not a string.

Here's the complete code listing (so that the answer is self-contained).

```
using System;               
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    // Solution to SO Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27159478/325521
    // This Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/
    // Author: Shiva Manjunath
    // SO Profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/325521/shiva
    public static void Main()
    {       
        string Jstring = @"{
        ""PolicyId"" :""xxxxxx"",
        ""PolicyHolder"" :{""title"":""Mr"", ""FirstName"":""test"", ""LastName"":""testLast""}
        }";
        
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(Jstring);
        JProperty jProperty = jObject.Properties().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PolicyHolder");
        
        Console.WriteLine("Printing Policy Holder Details....");
        Console.WriteLine(jProperty.Value);
    }
}

public class PolicyHolder
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Policy
{
    public string PolicyId { get; set; }
    public PolicyHolder PolicyHolder { get; set; }
}
```